# TensorFlow tf.data processing dev set after each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

```py
batch_size = 2
x_dim = 2
m = 5
m_dev = 4
epochs = 2

# Toy data
X_train = np.random.randn(m, x_dim)
Y_train = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=m).reshape(-1, 1)
X_dev = np.random.randn(m_dev, x_dim)
Y_dev = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=m_dev).reshape(-1, 1)

X = tf.placeholder(X_train.dtype, shape=[None, x_dim], name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(Y_train.dtype, shape=[None, 1], name='Y')

# Create two separate datasets
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y)).batch(batch_size)
dev_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y)).batch(X_dev.shape[0])

# Create a generic Iterator
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types,
                                           train_dataset.output_shapes)

# Create two init ops
train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
dev_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dev_dataset)

next_data = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Training data
        sess.run(train_init_op, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
        while True:
            try:
                X_batch, Y_batch = sess.run(next_data)
                # process training data
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break

        # Epoch done: process the dev data
        sess.run(dev_init_op, feed_dict={X: X_dev, Y: Y_dev})
        X_dev_all, Y_dev_all = sess.run(next_data)
```

I am using `tf.data` with reinitializable iterator to handle training and dev set data. For each epoch, I initialize the training data set. [The official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) has similar structure. I think this is not efficient especially if the training set is large.

Some of the resources I found online has `sess.run(train_init_op, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})` before the for loop to avoid this issue. But then we can't process the dev set after each epoch; we can only process it after we are done iterating over `epochs` epochs.

Is there a way to efficiently process the dev set after each epoch?

Comment: After each epoch of training you would like to run some operation on a part of the training set. And trying to do so, it is unclear where to reinitialize the dataset. Is that what you are trying to solve?

Comment: After each epoch of training data, I would like to calculate loss and accuracy on dev set, for which I have to run initialization on the dev set. After that, I have to reinitialize the training data for the next epoch. I am looking for an efficient way to handle the need to reinitialize the training data after each epoch.

Comment: To do exactly that you are on the right track: initialize your dataset again and run until you get OutOfRange error again. However, we often calculate loss and accuracy along with training operations, by feeding multiple ops at once `loss, acc, _ = sess.run([loss, acc, train_step], {})` - this way it will come at no cost while will be only slightly imprecise